# SonarQube thinks my variable is nullable here, while a custom exception would have been thrown if should be the case

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, sonarqube

```java
private void notFoundIfNull(Object o) {
  if (o == null) {
    throw new NotFoundException();
  }
}

public int run(Object o) {
  notFoundIfNull(o);
  return o.getIndex(); // <-- NullPointerException might be thrown as 'o' is nullable here
}
```

Is there any way to make SonarQube understand that `o` cannot be null here, as a `NotFoundException` would be thrown otherwise?

SonarJava v4.9.0.9858

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the version of SonarJava you have loaded in the SonarQube server.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam I'm a bit confused, but I haven't been able to find where to see the SonarJava version... Any hint?

Comment: @sp00m go to http://host-of-sonarqube/updatecenter/installed

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Version of SonarJava is 4.9.0.9858 (update 4.10 is proposed, not yet installed though).

Comment: @janos Are you able to replicate the issue I'm facing?

Comment: I'm observing a similar issue - in our case it is an assignment in a catch block (catching a custom runtime exception) that gets ignored.